# One page layout is not responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have created simple under construction html layout but I cannot make it responsive. On screen with 400px size and below I want the images and container 100% width.

Now the container has 400px fixed width. So the max-width property is not working as I expected.

#### FULL HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
<title>some title</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
<style>
    body {
        font-family: 'Arial', serif;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .container {
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto;     
        max-width: 400px;   
    }

    .container img {
        margin: 50px 0;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }

    p { 
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    a {
        color: red;
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/powr/defaults/image-slider2.jpg">
    <h1>some text</h1>
    <p>bla bla bla some text </p>
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/powr/defaults/image-slider2.jpg">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Arial', serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.container img {
  margin: 50px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

p {
  font-size: 16px;
}

a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/powr/defaults/image-slider2.jpg">
  <h1>some text</h1>
  <p>bla bla bla some text </p>
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/powr/defaults/image-slider2.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: trenccan how did you expect it to work?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/eh0161c6/ it is working exactly as you said...

Comment: Seems to be working in Chrome as well. Are you expecting something else or?

Comment: hmm, in the fiddle is working. Maybe browser has a problem to show me responsive page if Im opening index.html from desktop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` in the head section

Comment: FYI you also should add alt to images for proper html. Read this https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_alt.asp